# Why calling flash function from javascript fails for me?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flex3

I'm doing it this way:

```
...

public function j2fCall()
{
    Alert.show( "j2fCall?");
}

public function Main( nav: Navigation )
{
    if(ExternalInterface.available)
    {
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("javascriptUpdateSettings", j2fCall);
    }

    ...
}
```

But when I call `javascriptUpdateSettings` from javascript,only got the error:

```
javascriptUpdateSettings is not defined
```

What's wrong above?

**UPDATE**

I'm embedding swf and call it this way:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
swfobject.javascriptUpdateSettings();
```

Comment: You don't show how you call javascriptUpdateSettings() from JavaScript, are you aware that you need to call it as a method on a Flash object, like mySwf.javascriptUpdateSettings(), not just javascriptUpdateSettings()?

Comment: Showing your javascript would be great help

Comment: I tried `swfobject.javascriptUpdateSettings()`,but still the same..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `swfobject.getObjectById("myContent").javascriptUpdateSettings()`